# while missing next echo ignoring the same value

Tags: php

i trying create battle but i have problem because my code ignoring when values is the same or 2x higher its just show echo 1x

sorry for my bad english.

here my code:

```
$przeciwnik['predkosc'] = 2;
$gracz['predkosc'] =3;
$tura[walka] = 0;
while($tura[walka] < 30){

while($gracz['predkosc'] > $przeciwnik['predkosc']){
    $przeciwnik['predkosc'] += $przeciwnik['predkosc'];
echo'
attack player';

while($gracz['predkosc'] == $przeciwnik['predkosc']){
echo'
bonus tur';
$gracz['predkosc'] += $gracz['predkosc'];
}

while($przeciwnik['predkosc'] > $gracz['predkosc']){
echo '
other player tur';
$gracz['predkosc'] += $gracz['predkosc'];
}

}

$tura[walka] += 1;
}
```

output:

```
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
other player tur
attack player
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes when accessing the following entry :

```
$tura[walka]
```

Replace it with

```
$tura['walka']
```

everywhere in your code.

Comment: i change but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Can be please more specific what do you want to ask. As much I am getting from your question is that you should change 
`while($gracz['predkosc'] > $przeciwnik['predkosc']){
    $przeciwnik['predkosc'] += $przeciwnik['predkosc'];
echo'attack player';` 

 to 
 
`while($gracz['predkosc'] > $przeciwnik['predkosc']){
    $przeciwnik['predkosc'] += $przeciwnik['predkosc'];
echo'attack player';
}`

Remove second last brace from your code, and should resolve your problem.

Comment: this doesnt help still the same output.

Comment: Is your final code :- $przeciwnik['predkosc'] = 2;
$gracz['predkosc'] =3;
$tura[walka] = 0;
while($tura[walka] < 30){

while($gracz['predkosc'] > $przeciwnik['predkosc']){
    $przeciwnik['predkosc'] += $przeciwnik['predkosc'];
echo'attack player';
}
while($gracz['predkosc'] == $przeciwnik['predkosc']){
echo'
bonus tur';
$gracz['predkosc'] += $gracz['predkosc'];
}

while($przeciwnik['predkosc'] > $gracz['predkosc']){
echo '
other player tur';
$gracz['predkosc'] += $gracz['predkosc'];
}

$tura[walka] += 1;
}

Comment: There is change I have changed the braces please look carefully.  I have added curly brace ( closing curly brace } ) after "echo 'attack player'; ", and at last I have removed one curly brace before "$tura[walka] += 1;" this is what I could get from your code that why it is printing only one time. Please try this after performing the change which I suggested.